# Caching images with backbone Model

Tags: javascript, image, caching, backbone.js

I'm looking for a cache solution but I'm not sure what to do.

I have an url which is displaying an image, something like this
    http://www.louisetzeliemartin.org/medias/images/chat-1.jpg

The problem is that the image is heavy and slow to load. I'm fetching my model every 1min getting a new image url each time (real time data map).

What I want is that instead of just storing the image src and then load it normally i want to store the image itself so it's faster.

I hope it's clear. What should be the good approach for this ? Any specificity with backbone ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser should take care of caching resources automagically. If you have devtools open, you might have No Cache enabled and it's reloading every time for you.